# Error no such table: forms_complain in django

Tags: django

I have created a html file 'Complain' and its supposed to take input from user and store in in the database. My complain.html is

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title></title>
</head>
<body>
    <h1>Hello People</h1>
    <form action="/complain/" method="post">
        {% csrf_token %}
        <label for="name">Your Name</label>
        <input type="text" name="Std_name" placeholder="John Doe"><br><br>
        <label for="Std_id">Your Student ID</label>
        <input type="number" name="Std_id" placeholder="01"><br><br>
        <label for="Std_class">Your Class</label>
        <input type="text" name="Std_class" placeholder="Class 1"><br><br>
        <label for="email">Your Email</label>
        <input type="email" name="email" placeholder="abc@gmail.com"><br><br>
        <label for="desc">Your Complaint</label>
        <input type="text" name="desc"><br><br>
        <button type="submit">Submit</button>

    </form>

</body>
</html>
```

and models.py is

```
from django.db import models
from django.forms import ModelForm
from django.utils import timezone

class StudentFeedBack(models.Model):
    feedbackid = models.AutoField(primary_key=True)
    courseid = models.ForeignKey('Course', on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    description = models.CharField(max_length=500)
    submitdate = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    teacherid = models.ForeignKey('schoolTeacher', on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    studentid = models.ForeignKey('Student', on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    option = [('Good','Good'),('Average','Average'),('Bad','Bad')]
    rating = models.CharField(max_length=100, choices=option, default='none')
```

Views.py is

```
from django.shortcuts import render
from django.http import HttpResponse
from django.db.models import Q
from .models import Complaint, Complain

def complain(request):
    if request.method=='POST':
        name = request.POST.get("name")
        Std_id = request.POST.get("Std_id")
        Std_class = request.POST.get("Std_class")
        email = request.POST.get("email")
        desc = request.POST.get("desc")
        instance = Complain(name=name, Std_id=Std_id, Std_class=Std_class, email=email, desc=desc)
        instance.save()
        
    return render(request,'forms/complain.html', { 'title' : 'Complain'})
```

I have run `python manage.py makemigration`
`python manage.py migrate`
`python manage.py sqlmigrate forms`
and someone recommended on stack overflow to run

```
python manage.py migrate --run-syncdb
```

so I tried it too. But it did not worked.
My /admin does have Complain table but on clicking it it is showing error

```
OperationalError at /admin/forms/complain/
```

Comment: in migration folder remove last 2 migration files and try makemigrations and migrate command

Comment: It did not worked

Comment: OperationalError at /admin/forms/complain/ this error occur only while clicking the complain in admin?

Comment: Yes. And on clicking submit button

Comment: create model with removing `Std_no = models.AutoField(primary_key=True)`

Comment: It did not worked either